# Trouble aligning baselines of NSLayoutManager

Tags: ios, uiview, textkit, nslayoutmanager, nstextcontainer

I'm developing a custom `UIView` that renders text using a number of separate `NSLayoutManager` objects. (This view has text positioning requirements beyond what the built-in text view classes can support.) I'm having a hard time getting the correct vertical position for one of the layouts when the text being laid out is Hebrew. I apologize for the length of this post, but I wanted to include as much relevant detail as possible.

**The problem**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

The baseline for the "2" is nicely aligned with the baseline of the Hebrew letter "ו" (which is rendered in a custom font). However, if I switch the text of the "2" to a Hebrew number (actually the Hebrew letter "ב", which has value 2 in numerical contexts), it comes out like this (where the "ב" is too high):

[image]

The *only* change here is to the text string. Instead of `"2"`, it's `"\u{05b1}"`. I want everything to be on a common baseline and would appreciate any suggestions for fixing the problem (which happens for all Hebrew numbers, not just `"\u{05b1}"`).

**The code**

(I should mention that for technical reasons, I can't use a single `NSLayoutManager` for both the number and the main text.) I'm trying to align the baselines by vertically shifting the rendering position for the number by the difference in font ascents. Here's the code to compute the shift:

```
numberFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: /* some size */)
offset = fullFont.ascender - numberFont.ascender
```

Here's how I'm creating the `NSLayoutManager` for the number:

```
var lbl = "2" // or "\u{05b1}"

let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paraStyle.alignment = .center
let text = NSTextStorage(
    string: lbl,
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: numberFont,
                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle]
)

let layout = NSLayoutManager()
text.addLayoutManager(layout)
let container = NSTextContainer(
    size: CGSize(width: /* some fixed width */, height: bounds.height - offset)
)
container.lineFragmentPadding = 0
layout.addTextContainer(container)

let x = ... // irrelevant
let origin = CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.minY + offset)
```

Later, I render the text using:

```
let range = layout.glyphRange(for: layout.textContainers[0])
layout.drawGlyphs(forGlyphRange: range, at: origin)
```

The main text is handled using identical logic but with no `offset` (and a different font, of course). This works beautifully for Arabic numerals (e.g., "2"), but fails for Hebrew numbers (e.g., "ב").

**Further information**

For the images above, the font size (`.pointSize`) and ascent (`.ascender`) properties are:

> sizes: text = 14.3890409469604 ; number = 8.63342465753425
>   ascents: text = 16.159567469731 ; number = 8.2203017979452

I also generating some diagnostic information about the layouts, but the numbers don't make a lot of sense to me. Here's the code for printing out the information:

```
size = text.size()
mgr = NSLayoutManager()
text.addLayoutManager(mgr)
container = NSTextContainer(
    size: CGSize( width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude,
                 height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
container.lineFragmentPadding = 0
mgr.addTextContainer(container)
mgr.ensureLayout(for: container)
range = mgr.glyphRange(for: container)

print("label:", lbl)
print("  text size:", size)
print("     bounds:", mgr.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: range, in: container))
```

And here are the results for the two texts ("2" and "\u{05d1}"):

> label: 2
>       text size: (5.3958904109589, 10.3027782534247)
>         bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 5.3958904109589, 10.3027782534247)
>    label: ב
>      text size: (4.67931616438356, 9.19459726027397)
>        bounds: (-1.88208657534247, -0.578439452054793, 9.5054005479452, 9.77303671232876)

Several things about this puzzle me:

- the bounds for the for the Hebrew text start at negative values for x and y. The negative x origin may have something to do with Hebrew being a right-to-left script, but what about the negative y origin?
- the reported size of the layout is the algebraic sum of the height of the bounds and the y start of the bounds or (perhaps more precisely) the bottom of the text in the container, not the actual overall size. Is `NSAttributedString.size()` broken?
- none of the numbers seem to explain the visual difference in the vertical position of the "2" and of the "\u{05d1}".

Comment: What happens if you put "2" and "\u{05d1}" in the same string next to each other?

Comment: @DaveWeston - Aha! When I tried that, it lowered the `"\u{05d1}"` to where it was supposed to be. After playing around a bit, this led to an acceptable solution: add a zero-width space (`"\u{200b}"`) before the `"\u{05d1}"`. While this fixes the problem as far as getting my screen to look right, I'd sure like to know what's going on and why such a kludge is necessary.

Comment: I love a puzzle. Can you put together a tiny project or playground that demonstrates the problem? I've read through the attributed string guide but nothing jumps out at me.